# Exposing Istio Ingress Gateway as NodePort to GKE and run health check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm running Istio Ingress Gateway in a GKE cluster. The `Service` runs with a NodePort. I'd like to connect it to a Google backend service. However we need to have an health check that must run against Istio. Do you know if Istio expose any HTTP endpoint to run health check and verify its status?

Comment: what do you mean by "Google backend service"?

Answer (score 0):

Per this [installation guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio), "Istio requires no changes to the application itself. Note that the application must use HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.0 protocol for all its HTTP traffic because the Envoy proxy doesn't support HTTP/1.0: it relies on headers that aren't present in HTTP/1.0 for routing."

Answer (score 0):

The healthcheck doesn't necessarily run against Istio itself, but against the whole stack behind the IP addresses you configured for the load balancer backend service. It simply requires a 200 response on `/` when invoked with no host name.

You can configure this by installing a small service like httpbin as the default path for your gateway.

You might also consider changing your `Service` to a LoadBalancer type, annotated to be internal to your network (no public IP).  This will generate a Backend Service, complete with healthcheck, which you can borrow for your other load balancer.  This method has worked for me with nesting load balancers (to migrate load) but not for a proxy like Google's IAP.